# Join Left or WHERE solution - Most efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am learning about databases at college, and have the assignment about finding the minimum avg exam grade for a college course. I have made two solutions, but I hope you experts in here can help me with:

What is the best/most effective solution?

Solution 1:

```
SELECT courses.name , MIN(avg_grade)
FROM (SELECT courseCode, AVG(grade) as avg_grade
      FROM exams
      GROUP BY courseCode) avg_grades, courses
WHERE courses.code = avg_grades.courseCode
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT name, min(avg_grade)
FROM (SELECT courses.name, AVG(grade) as avg_grade
      FROM courses
      LEFT JOIN exams on exams.courseCode = courses.code
      GROUP BY courseCode) mytable
```

And I have been thinking about if JOIN or LEFT JOIN is the correct to use here?

Comment: Using a left join suggests that you want grades from courses that have had no exams.  Are you sure about that?

Comment: So this will result in a NULL value if there is no EXAM that match the COURSE? Will that be prevented with using JOIN, and how will my AVG react on the 2 different solutions?

Comment: Make the left join to an inner join (I'd say, this is what you want anyway), then execute the queries with the keyword `EXPLAIN` in front of them and see if you can spot any differences. I'd say there will be none. And [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) you can read up about joins, it's a quite good explanation.

Comment: Since you are in college, I suggest taking the opportunity to improve your coding style.  Specifically, your group by clauses might work with MySql, but they will not work with other database engines.  The method that works with all database engines is to group by all and only the non-aggregate selections in your select clause.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the link fancypants! To Dan Bracuk: We have been told to use the MySQL syntax for our exercises, but i would love to learn a more general way. But im not sure i understand how you want it to work without the group by? Oh, and does any of you have a suggestion for what the best solution is of the two? I bet on the JOIN solution?

Comment: A lot of times the database engine ends up optimizing similar queries to work exactly the same way in the background. The only way to know for sure will be to follow fancyPants suggestion of using `EXPLAIN`

Comment: My intuition tells me that Solution 1 is the better of the two.  Back to the group by stuff.  MySql makes group by clauses optional.  Adding one to solution 1 will not make the syntax invalid for mysql.  In solution 2, adding course code to the select clause of your subquery and grouping by both fields will still be valid mysql syntax.

Comment: If you mean "faster", then say "faster", not "more efficient."  Efficiency can come in many areas: Memory usage, disk usage, programmer time, execution time, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two queries are different, so you can't really compare efficiency, your second query will return records for courses with no exam results.
Assuming that you switch the LEFT JOIN to an INNER to make the queries comparable, then I would expect the first query to be slightly more efficient since it only has one
derived table, and the second has two:

Solution 1:

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE     TABLE   TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY KEY_LEN REF ROWS    FILTERED    EXTRA
1   PRIMARY         ALL                                             5       100 
1   PRIMARY courses ALL                                             5       100     Using where; Using join buffer
2   DERIVED exams   ALL                                             5       100     Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Solution 2:

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE     TABLE   TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY KEY_LEN REF ROWS    FILTERED    EXTRA
1   PRIMARY         ALL                                             5       100 
2   DERIVED courses ALL                                             5       100         Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED exams   ALL                                             5       100         Using where; Using join buffer
```

I would however check this against your own execution plans as mine was just a quick example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9053/5).

I would like to take this chance to advise against using the ANSI-89 implicit join syntax, it was replaced over 20 years ago by the explicit join syntax in the ANSI-92 standard. Aaron Bertrand has written a [great article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) on why to switch, I won't duplicate it here.

Another, much more important point though is that your queries are not deterministic, that is to say you could run the same query twice and get 2 different results even with no underlying change in the data.

Taking your second query as an example (although you will notice both queries are wrong on the SQL-Fiddle), you have a subquery `MyTable` like so:

```
SELECT courses.name, AVG(grade) as avg_grade
FROM courses
LEFT JOIN exams on exams.courseCode = courses.code
GROUP BY courseCode
```

This returned a table like so:

```
Name    |   avg_grade
--------+--------------
   A    |       10
   B    |       5
   C    |       6
   D    |       7
   E    |       2
```

You may expect the query as a whole to return:

```
Name    |   avg_grade
--------+--------------
   E    |       2
```

Since 2 is the lowest average grade, and E is the name that corresponds with that. You would be wrong though, [as demonstrated here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9053/3) you can see this actually returns:

```
Name    |   avg_grade
--------+--------------
   A    |       2
```

What is essentially happening is that MySQL is calculating the minimum avg_grade correctly, but since you have not added any columns to the group by you have given MySQL Carte blanche to choose any value for `Name` it chooses.

To get the output you want, I think you need:

```
SELECT  courses.name , MIN(avg_grade)
FROM    (   SELECT  courseCode, AVG(grade) as avg_grade
            FROM    exams
            GROUP BY courseCode
        ) avg_grades
        INNER JOIN courses
            ON courses.code = avg_grades.courseCode
GROUP BY courses.Name;
```

Or if you only want to the course with the lowest average grade then use:

```
SELECT  courseCode, AVG(grade) as avg_grade
FROM    exams
GROUP BY courseCode
ORDER BY avg_grade
LIMIT 1;
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9053/6)**

Please excuse the laziness of what I am about to do, but I have explained this problem a lot before, and now have a standard response that I post to explain the issue of MySQL grouping. It goes into more detail than the above, and hopefully explains it further.

---

**MySQL Implicit Grouping**

I would advise to avoid the implicit grouping offered by MySQL where possible, by this i mean including columns in the select list, even though they are not contained in an aggregate function or the group by clause.

Imagine the following simple table (T):

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |
----|---------+----------|
1   |    A    |    X     |
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

In MySQL you can write

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY Column1;
```

This actually breaks the SQL Standard, but it works in MySQL, however the trouble is it is non-deterministic, the result:

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |
----|---------+----------|
1   |    A    |    X     |
```

Is no more or less correct than

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |  
----|---------+----------|
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

So what you are saying is give me one row for each distinct value of `Column1`, which both results sets satisfy, so how do you know which one you will get? Well you don't, it seems to be a fairly popular misconception that you can add and `ORDER BY` clause to influence the results, so for example the following query:

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY Column1
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

Would ensure that you get the following result:

```
ID  | Column1 | Column2  |  
----|---------+----------|
2   |    A    |    Y     |
```

because of the `ORDER BY ID DESC`, however this is not true ([as demonstrated here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b917/1)).

The [MySQL documents](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) state:

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

So even though you have an order by this does not apply until after one row per group has been selected, and this one row is non-deterministic.

The SQL-Standard does allow columns in the select list not contained in the GROUP BY or an aggregate function, however these columns must be functionally dependent on a column in the GROUP BY. For example, ID in the sample table is the PRIMARY KEY, so we know it is unique in the table, so the following query conforms to the SQL standard and would run in MySQL and fail in many DBMS currently (At the time of writing Postgresql is the closest DBMS I know of to correctly implementing the standard):

```
SELECT  ID, Column1, Column2
FROM    T
GROUP BY ID;
```

Since ID is unique for each row, there can only be one value of `Column1` for each ID, one value of `Column2` there is no ambiguity about what to return for each row.

**EDIT**

From the SQL-2003-Standard (5WD-02-Foundation-2003-09 - page 346) - http://www.wiscorp.com/sql_2003_standard.zip

> 15. If T is a grouped table, then let G be the set of grouping columns of T. In each  contained
>     in  , each column reference that references a column of T shall reference some column C that
>     is functionally dependent on G or shall be contained in an aggregated argument of a 
>     whose aggregation query is QS.

Comment: Could you please post a reference for "*The SQL-Standard does allow columns in the select list not contained in the GROUP BY or an aggregate function, however these columns must be functionally dependent on a column in the GROUP BY.*". Thank you.

Comment: Amazing answer, you just saved me doing a mistake, for by incedent my own queries returned the correct answer, but only because the first in my list had the lowest grade. Thanks for all your time to explain this for me and everyone else who might come across this in the future, its simply wonderful!

Comment: @PM77-1 I have edited the answer and added the page and section of the SQL-2003 standard that states it, and also a link to the standard. Hope this helps.